# Efficient (divergent) summation for sum of zetas at negative arguments?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divergent-series, zeta-functions, sequences-and-series

In a [question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363811/alternating-sum-of-multiple-zetas-equals-always-1/364212#364212) (see bottom of my own answer) I'm considering the following series, depending on a parameter *m*:
$$ L(m) = -\zeta(1m)/1 - \zeta(2m)/2 - \zeta(3m)/3 - \ldots $$
where I want to make sense of that sums at negative *m*.

For the numerical evaluation I use a customized version of the Noerlund-summation ($ \mathfrak N $) (with the software Pari/GP), but which converges only poorly and even with 128 terms I get not much more than some 15 correct digits.
However, at least for $m=-1$ I get a convincing guess using mathematica (at wolfram alpha) such that
$$L(-1) \underset{\mathfrak N}{=} 1- \log( \sqrt{2 \pi}) \qquad \small \text{ // guessed from 15 digits }$$
For fractional *m* between $0 \gt m \gt -1$ the summation still works in principle but with even less reliable digits precision. Here are some guesses for $B(m) = \exp(L(m))$
$$ \small \begin{array} {r|lr}
 m & B(m) (\text{ using } \mathfrak N ) \\
\hline
 -1 & 1.0844375514192275466 & \qquad (=\exp(1)/ \sqrt{2 \pi} = 1-A_{-1})\\
 -1/2 & 1.2904007518681174634 \\
 -1/3 & 1.48044921903 \\
 -1/4 & 1.65184851943 \\
 \end{array} $$

Unfortunately for $m \lt -1$ my procedures seem to be completely useless.
So I'd like to ask here:
**Q:** Which (efficient) procedure can I use to get meaningful evaluations for $L(m)$ at negative *m* ?

**[update]**
To respond to @joro's computation: I did also a Borel-summation. The result for $L(-1)$ was $$L(-1) \sim 0.08106146679532725821967026359438236013860...$$

I proceeded this way. My function to be summed at -1 is
$$ L(m) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(km)/k \qquad \text{ at } m=-1$$

The Borel-transform is
$$ \mathfrak B L(-1) = - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \zeta(-1-k)/(1+k) \cdot x^k/k! $$
and we define 
$$ B_0(x) = - 1/x \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(-k) \cdot x^k/k! $$
(where the index is also conveniently adapted)

Then the Borel-sum is computed by the integral
$$ L(-1) \underset{\mathfrak B}{=}\int_0^\infty \exp(-t) B_0(t) dt $$

Now using the software Pari/GP and the sumalt-procedure for $B_0(x)$ we are still confined to small *x*, so the integral cannot be evaluated at high values of *t* . But the $B_0(x)$ can be expressed in a closed form using only the exponential, which I denote here as $B_1(x)$:
$$ B_1(x)= \left(\frac 12- \frac 1x  -{1 \over 1-\exp(x)}\right) \cdot \frac 1x $$
This integral can now be evaluated numerically by Pari/GP with a far better interval:
$$ L(-1) \underset{\mathfrak B}{\sim}\int_{1e-20}^{1e6} \exp(-t) B_1(t) dt $$
and gives the above value to about 30 digits precision (I don't think it is a rational value).

Unfortunately, I cannot generalize that transformation to closed form for sequences of $\zeta(1m)/1,\zeta(2m)/2 , \zeta(3m)/3, ...$ where a negative $m$ is different from $-1$, say $m=-1/2$ or $m=-3$ ...
[/update]

Comment: For m=-1 all sumation methods of mpmath give the rational value 0.0815957190957190957190957190.

Comment: ......for L(-1) 

Comment: @joro: are you sure that are methods for divergent summation? And if, are they strong enough? For instance, using "sumalt" in Pari/GP is not strong enough although it is in general a very useful procedure for divergent summation.

Comment: joro: mpmath.nsum does not work well if some terms are zero. Excluding those gives 0.081061466795328 (it does not appear possible to get much more accuracy).

Comment: ok, I don't claim the answer is correct, just wrote what mpmath returns.

Comment: So, for $m=-1$, did you prove it? or is it just a numerical approximation?

Comment: Using that $\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi$, I could prove that the approximation you have is correct.

Comment: @i707107: no, I've no proof for the guessed algebaric identity; so far it is only the numerical allusion - however I've got it to 40 digits instead of 15 now...

Comment: I will write proof of $m=-1$ case as an answer. 

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer for $m=-1$, proving that Gottfried Helms' guess is correct.

What we need is the following:

When $$B_1(x)= \left(\frac 12- \frac 1x  -{1 \over 1-\exp(x)}\right) \cdot \frac 1x, $$

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(-t) B_1(t) dt {=}1- \log( \sqrt{2 \pi})  $$

I have used the same idea for this question in MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340718/references-to-integrals-of-the-form-int-01-left-frac1-log-x-frac/342072#342072

The idea is considering the following integral:

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac 12- \frac 1t  -{1 \over 1-\exp(t)}\right) \cdot t^{s-1} e^{-t} dt$$

This is well-defined if $\textrm{Re}(s)>-1$. In particular for $s=0$.

This integral can be treated term by term if we have $s$ with sufficiently large real part (absolute convergence).

The result is 
$$\frac 12 \Gamma(s) - \Gamma(s-1) + \Gamma(s)(\zeta(s)-1)$$

Since the integral defines analytic function on $\textrm{Re}(s)>-1$, the result of integral should be analytic continuation of the function $\frac 12 \Gamma(s) - \Gamma(s-1) + \Gamma(s)(\zeta(s)-1)$.

Now the result for $s=0$ follows if we take limit $s\rightarrow 0$ in that expression.

Comment: hmm, if I feed the last mentioned function into Pari/GP I get for $s=\epsilon$ the result of $\epsilon^{−1}$ for epsilon near zero

Comment: That must be an error, this function does have limit as $s\rightarrow 0$, and it is $1+\zeta'(0)$. 

Comment: See this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%28.000001%29%28Zeta%28.000001%29-1%2F2-1%2F%28.000001+-1%29%29


Comment: I see; I've made a sign-error, sorry.